# Why ReactQuery fetches again and not use its cache?

Tags: react-query

I have simple react app with slider. The role of slider is to present fetched thumbnails of videos. This slider has "up" and "down" buttons which slide content and also (as the fetching is limited by admin to 25 in single fetch) generates fetch action for more data when needed.

The slider then can work in up direction and down direction. Clear enough. To fetch data, I took React Query just for its caching abilities. I wanted the slider to keep data, e.g. when I slide up I fetch the data, but when I slide down I have data cached and no fetch action is called. Unfortunately, it does not work. Sliding down, I see fetching again.
The config is as follows:

defaults in useQueryClient hook:

```
const useQueryClient = () => {
    const { showError, completeLoading } = useDispatchAction();

    const queryErrorHandler = (err: unknown): void => {
        const axiosError = err as AxiosError;
        completeLoading();
        showError({ isError: true, errorMessage: axiosError.message });
    };

    const defaultQueryClientOptions = {
        queries: {
            onError: queryErrorHandler,
            retry: false,
            cacheTime: 1.1 * (60 * 1000),
            refetchOnMount: false,
            refetchOnWindowFocus: false,
            staleTime: 1 * (60 * 1000),
            refetchInterval: 1 * (60 * 1000),
        },
    };

    return new QueryClient({
        defaultOptions: defaultQueryClientOptions,
    });
};

export default useQueryClient;
```

TanstackQueryProvider (for React reasons I must use above in separate provider)

```
import { QueryClientProvider } from "@tanstack/react-query";
import { useDispatchAction, useQueryClient } from "hooks";
import { QueryClient } from "@tanstack/react-query";
import React from "react";
import { ReactNode } from "react";
import { AxiosError } from "axios";

export const TanstackQueryProvider: React.FC<{ children: ReactNode }> = ({ children }) => {
    // const queryClient = useQueryClient();

    const { showError, completeLoading } = useDispatchAction();

    const queryErrorHandler = (err: unknown): void => {
        const axiosError = err as AxiosError;
        completeLoading();
        showError({ isError: true, errorMessage: axiosError.message });
    };

    const defaultQueryClientOptions = {
        queries: {
            onError: queryErrorHandler,
            retry: false,
            cacheTime: 1.1 * (60 * 1000),
            refetchOnMount: false,
            refetchOnWindowFocus: false,
            staleTime: 1 * (60 * 1000),
            refetchInterval: 1 * (60 * 1000),
        },
    };

    const [queryClient] = React.useState(
        () =>
            new QueryClient({
                defaultOptions: defaultQueryClientOptions,
            })
    );

    return <QueryClientProvider client={queryClient}>{children}</QueryClientProvider>;
};

export default TanstackQueryProvider;
```

main index file

```
const container = document.getElementById("root");
const root = createRoot(container as Element);
root.render(
    <AppProvider>
        <TanstackQueryProvider>
            <App />
        </TanstackQueryProvider>
    </AppProvider>
);
```

so, you see the query client is created outside App itself

query itself:

```
    const { isLoading, data, refetch, isFetching, isPreviousData } = useQuery({
        queryKey: ["users", url],
        queryFn: () => fetchThumbnails(url),
        enabled: Boolean(url),
        keepPreviousData: true,
    });
```

actual fetching function:

```
export const fetchThumbnails = async (url: string) => {
    const response = await fetch(url);
    if (!response.ok) {
        const status = response.status;
        const result = await response.json();
        throw new Error(`${status} ${result?.error?.message || "unknown error"}`);
    }
    const data = response.json();
    console.log("url", url); 
    return data;
};
```

I have rechecked URL's to be sure. Yes, these are the same strings when I slide up and slide down. The same URL, so it should be the same key, and it should be cached. Why isn't?

Comment: this should work, at least within one minute, because that's what your staleTime is set to; maybe your QueryClient isn't stable? (https://tkdodo.eu/blog/react-query-fa-qs#2-the-queryclient-is-not-stable) hard to say without seeing a runnable reproduction

Comment: @TkDodo I have edited above post, now one can see also general architecture of application. Is the query stable? It is created outside of App for sure. The code one can see here: https://github.com/Kiszuriwalilibori/youtube and working app here:https://kiszuriwalilibori.github.io/youtube/  email: any technically valid email, pwd: MISIO  The initial slider content is random, to reproduce the issue type for example "cats" and slide up with button (it fetches next page after roughly 24 clicks)

Comment: no, its not stable. Your `useQueryClient` hook returns a `new QueryClient` on every render

Comment: @TkDodo I have refactored TanstackQueryprovider to be very similar to 3: You sometimes can't export section code on your blog. So, useQueryClient is no more in use (but not removed). TanstackQueryProvider took whole its job. Unfortunately, the behaviour has not changed - still not caching, why?